# False positive Errors on Jetbrains IDEs

Tags: error, dev, solo-chain

I’m currently using VSCode to develop a chain based on Substrate, and want to switch to CLion or IntelliJ IDEA, but after setting up these IDEs, the inspection reports more than 90 errors in my project…

Errors are mostly import errors and misc false positive rust errors.

I'm using cargo check as external linter.

Cargo check and cargo build manually don’t report any errors and all is compiling with success, and I don’t have any of theses errors in my VSCode + Rust-analyzer setup.

Does anyone had this problem ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I do have the same problem, I suppose the [Rust plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8182-rust) can still be improved.

In my case I only have `Unresolved reference` errors.

The inspections settings can be configured to skip one or more specific errors:

Go to Settings > Editor > Inspections, then you can uncheck the error `Unresolved reference`, or any false positive error.

[image]

Another option is to convert the error into a (weak) warning.

Note that this change might also affects real errors.